# How to Set Password During Command Line Execution

Tags: node.js, passwords, root, sudo

I am trying to run a command line execution from Node over SSH, but am having issues running with root privileges.

```
const util = require('util')
const exec = require('child_process').exec

function set(pin, state) {
  exec('sudo bash -c "do something"', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) console.log('code', error.code)
  })
}
```

When I try to run without the sudo command it exits with `Code 1`.

Since ultimately I want to run this script when an API endpoint receives a request, I would like to run this command like `exec('command', 'password', (err, stdout, err)...`

**Can I pass in a password to the `exec` function to prevent a command line prompt?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo 'password' | sudo -S command
```

Be aware that your password will be stored in history.

Comment: I am running it as a script, so it's not showing up in history. Unless, I am missing something...